# How to make UICollectionView animate insertions relatively to its center?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

I'm using `UICollectionView` with `NSDiffableDataSource` and `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, which looks like horizontal sequence of covers.
By default, the insert animation looks like all the cells right to the inserted cell are moved to the right after insertion, like this:

```
before:

       center
         |
[1] [2] [3] [4] [5]

after we've added X between 1 and 2:

       center
         |
[1] [X] [2] [3] [4]... (5 is offscreen)
```

But what i want to achive is that if we add an item to the left of the center, then collection expands to the left, and respectively if we add an item to the right then it expands to the right, leaving the middle where it was originally. Like this:

```
after we've added X between 1 and 2:

   |       center      |
   |         |         |
...|[X] [2] [3] [4] [5]| (1 is offscreen now)

after we've added X between 3 and 4:

   |       center      |
   |         |         |
   |[1] [2] [3] [X] [4]|... (5 is offscreen)
```

I've tried using `scrollTo / selectItem(at:animated:scrollPosition:)` with `scrollPosition = .centeredHorizontally` and `indexPath` of item which was centered originally, both animated and not, but it looks bad, twitching because insertion and scroll animations overlap.

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: @RoiMulia As I can remember, i did some crutch to achieve this behaviour. I guess i had to calculate total width of the offscreen cells, and if there were more than half of the screen width, i used `scrollTo` without animation, so it looked like the item was kept in place.
And in case where we are close to left/right end of the collection, the default behaviour applies instead of this.